# NSDate into users current timezone/area for time in future

Tags: uitableview, nsdate

I'm working on an app that allows the user to select a date/time from a UITableView of times (half hour increments) everything goes fine and dandy until I get my final time. Since it's GMT the phone auto converts it into local time and throws off the schedule. The time they select needs to be converted into GMT + offset (since the user is selecting local time not GMT) so that the time they select is the time that's added to their calendar.

```
NSDate* newDate = [[scheduled objectForKey:@"date"] dateByAddingTimeInterval:1800.0*indexPath.row];
    [scheduled setObject:newDate forKey:@"date"];
```

As you can see right now I'm just taking base GMT and adding 1800s (30Min) per indexPath.row this works to get the correct time in GMT but really I need to be doing the same but from the users current timezone (And I guess convert that to GMT since you're supposed to store times in GMT)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOff = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:[scheduled objectForKey:@"date"]];

NSDate *gmtDate = [[scheduled objectForKey:@"date"] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-timeZoneOff];
```

Works like a charm.